# How to insert a lead through forcetk in salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce

js to get data from salesforce .The following function fetches data of a current logged In user from salesforce .

```
function init() {
  // Get an instance of the REST API client and set the session ID
  var client = new forcetk.Client();
  client.setSessionToken(getValueFromCookie("sid"));
  // Retrieve the data representing the current user
  client.currentUser(function(response){
    var user = response;
    console.log(user);
    // Find cases that belong to the current user
    client.query("SELECT Name FROM User", function(response){
        console.log(response);
        Tinycon.setBubble(response.totalSize);
    });         
  });
}
```

Now i want to insert a lead in salesforce through forcetk in current user which is logged In.